# Parameter wurdiynd

Tags: parametrization

How would I parameterise this curve in 3D?
I am confused since the diagrams deal with three variables in total – should I use complex numbers? I'm only used to two diagrams and haven't encountered a problem with three like this.

Comment: Shouldn't the equations of the lines in the last diagram have $z=\pm3y/(2\pi)$ instead?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your reply, that is a great point. On reflection it should be yes, sorry for making that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projection in the  $xy$-plane looks like an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral). Except that everything in the $y$-direction is doubled. The formulas
$$
x=t \cos t,\qquad y=2t\sin t
$$
match with the first figure perfectly. The given points correspond to $t=9\pi/2$,
$t=5\pi$, $t=11\pi/2$ and $t=6\pi$ - all in the third revolution $t\in[4\pi,6\pi]$.

The two latter figures give the impression that the curve lies on the
elliptical cone
$$
(3x)^2+(3y/2)^2=(\pi z)^2.
$$
Plugging in the first two equations gives
$$
(3x)^2+(3y/2)^2=9t^2(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)=9t^2,
$$
so we can solve that $z=3t/\pi$.

Here's a 3D view of that parametrized curve by Mathematica

[image]

together with a view from the side

[image]

---

How to? The Archimedean spirals (as well as the logarithmic spirals) occur in all books about polar coordinates. I had a bit of luck spotting that the four points you have fit on an Archimedean spiral, if you stretch it by a factor of two in the direction of $y$-axis. The latter two sketches give that we  should always have $z\ge0, |x|\le \pi z/3, |y|\le2\pi z/3$, also implying that everything in the $y$-direction is stretched by a factor of two. Going from these data points to a curve on a cone is just 3D-imagination. Anyway, here is the curve
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cl}x&=t\cos t,\\ y&=2t\sin t,\\ z&=3t/\pi\end{array}\right.
$$
one more time together with the surface of the above elliptical cone.

[image]

Comment: Oops! I had accidentally halved some of the values of the parameter $t$ that match with the given points of the first diagram. Sorry about that. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Wow thank you, amazing work, Sorry about the error before, and thank you for providing such clear work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

in $xy$ plane, you use polar coordinates as follows.

$x=r\cos(t)$ and  $y=r\sin(t)$ with

$r=ae^{-bt}$ and you choose the right parameters $a,b.$

to get  $z$ , you replace $x$.

Comment: A logarithmic spiral does come to mind from the first figure. But you need to take into account that it is bulging out in the direction of the $y$-axis, so this doesn't quite fit.

Comment: It remains the basis idea.

Comment: On second thought a logarithmic spiral does not fit at all. It never reaches the origin. Only approaches it. Use an Archimedean spiral instead.

Comment: try $ae^{-bt}+ce^{-dt}$  since you have $4$ conditions to satisfy. it goes to the origin.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I have tried this, thank you for posting - although say I were to take the coordinates (6pi,0) then I have: 6pi = r cos(t) and 0 =r sin(t). Which naturally follows that tan(t)=0, hence arctan of both sides results in t=0? Which does not really folllow. Similarly if I let the coordinates be (0,9pi) then I have the equations: 9pi=rsin(t) [1] and 0=rcos(t) [2] and when I do [1] / [2] it isn't possible since 9pi/0 does not exist :l